# BulkInsert - The space 'CSSpace' has no associated collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert

few days ago I encountered one of the most known problems in EF, the bulk insert. After some googling I found this: http://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

After failing with a complex data model I went back to a simple tester.
The entity I'm trying to insert looks like this:
Id - Int
Name - String

The entity is generated using VS and then followed the DB all using VS built in features.
I tried both EFs, 4 and 5. None worked. the exception is:

**The space 'CSSpace' has no associated collection.**

The exception is identical on both data models.

I use all the dependencies I have to as far as I know.

The code:

```
using (Model1Container ctx = new Model1Container())
{
    List<TestEntity> list = new List<TestEntity>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TestEntity enti = ctx.TestEntitySet.Create();
        enti.Name = "stav" + i;
        list.Add(enti);
        ctx.TestEntitySet.Add(enti);
    }

    ctx.BulkInsert<TestEntity>(list);
}
```

The stacktrace is this:

```
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, Boolean required)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace)
   at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappers.MapperBase.get_TphData() in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappers\MapperBase.cs:line 59
   at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappers.MapperBase.MapEntity(String typeFullName, EdmType edmItem) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappers\MapperBase.cs:line 284
   at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappings.DbMapping..ctor(DbContext context) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappings\DbMapping.cs:line 80
   at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.EfMap.Get(DbContext context) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\EfMap.cs:line 60
   at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Extensions.MappingApiExtensions.Db(DbContext ctx, Type type) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Extensions\MappingApiExtensions.cs:line 51
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
   at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Helpers.MappedDataReader`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 enumerable, IEfBulkInsertProvider provider) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Helpers\MappedDataReader.cs:line 58
   at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.Run[T](IEnumerable`1 entities, SqlTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.cs:line 22
   at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.ProviderBase`2.Run[T](IEnumerable`1 entities, IDbTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\ProviderBase.cs:line 77
   at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.ProviderBase`2.Run[T](IEnumerable`1 entities, BulkInsertOptions options) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\ProviderBase.cs:line 109
   at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.BulkInsertExtension.BulkInsert[T](DbContext context, IEnumerable`1 entities, SqlBulkCopyOptions sqlBulkCopyOptions, Nullable`1 batchSize) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Extensions\BulkInsertExtension.cs:line 95
   at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.BulkInsertExtension.BulkInsert[T](DbContext context, IEnumerable`1 entities, Nullable`1 batchSize) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Extensions\BulkInsertExtension.cs:line 75
   at TestApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\CCViews\I0T_PIMBuilder_dev\Tashtiot_VOB\PIMBuilder_COMP\TestApp\Program.cs:line 25
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah. Fix your metadata / mapping classes /whatever is wrong. Dumping a stack trace on us will not help. Too little information.

Comment: All the metadata is VS generated, didn't touch it. The metadata is well configured because when I use simple EF w/o extentions it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This library was made for code-first. I haven't finished DB-first yet.